# header file include paths

Tags: php, html, path, include

All this is contained within a folder inside my `public_html` folder.

```
/Public_Html
    /folder
        /css
            -style.css
        /includes
            -shop.css
            -header.php
            -footer.php
        /php
        /js
        /shop
            -index.php

        -index.php <-- homepage
        -config.php
```

Inside my config.php I have

define('ROOT_PATH',''http://example.net/folder');

My header.php has this at the top

```
<?php include '../config.php';?>
```

The problem is, I wish to only include the config file within header.php but make the path to it work whatever directory it is in. So for instance it will work fine in `/shop` but not the root index file of the folder because the path to `config.php` is then incorrect.

Any suggestions?

Comment: 1. What shop.css does in includes if you have already css directory? 
2. Use absolute paths instead of relative and problem solved.

Comment: @Robert Because it's only included on the shop index.php. Therefor it's an include and the css paths are written within the header.php which is included on every page.

Answer (score 0):

always include using realpath.

```
include realpath(__DIR__ . '/'. './config.php');
```

in config.php include files in this way

```
include realpath(__DIR__ . '/'. './includes/header.php');
```

if not PHP5.3

```
include realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/'. './includes/header.php');
```

Comment: The header isn't including within the config.php. The config.php is included within the header.